# Bogus face in 2.8 mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

My mesh shows what looks like a bogus face normal. The mesh and screen cap show the problem. Some holes still show a face normal but no face can be selected!

I got to this point by creating a building mesh and merging vertices. I created a separate mesh (plane) for cutting holes in the building. I used knife project to put cut lines into the building. Then I selected and removed faces where holes should be. Some holes still show a face normal even though there is a hole (no face can be selected). Merging vertices does nothing.

This appears to be a problem, but I don't know if it causes anything bad.

[image]

[[image]("https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9hFq.jpg)

Comment: I understand that the normal will show based on the median position of the face. This means you may have the normal 'coming out from a hole'. If you merged verticies (make sure you have the object selected) then also try Mesh > Clean up > Delete Loose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Barkest* has the answer, I believe. The "bogus" faces have surrounding real faces whose medium centers just happen to be over a hole, giving the false impression that there is a face where a hole exists.